# JPA - How to create entities where EntityA saves list ids of another table

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have an EntityA , and EntityB.

EntityB is a master table.

EntityA can have multiple id's of Entity B. So A column of EntityA should hold list/set of ids of EntityB.

I should be able to query EntityA, to get list of Ids of EntityB.

Note: Many rows in EntityA can refer to same id of EntityB

I tried below, but it I don't see column

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "todo")
private List<ObjectStore> store = new ArrayList<>();
```

Please can I ask how to do this using Spring JPA.

**EDIT:**

```
@Entity
public class Dept {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotNull(message = "name is mandatory")    
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotNull(message = "name is mandatory")    
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "DEPT", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="id"))
    private List<String> dept = new ArrayList<String>(4);
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }    
}
```

I observed that DEPT column got added to dept table. This is unwanted.

Use Case: Employee can hold list of departments. Many employee records, should be able to have same dept references.

Comment: Post your EntityA and EntityB contents

Answer (score 0):

You should change table name from "DEPT". Because @CollectionTable will create another embedded table with given name. In you case dept is already there so it will create new column in Dept.

```
// Employee Class
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "DEPT_EMPLOYEE_MAPPING", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="Employee_id"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="Dept_Id")
    private Map<Dept,DeptEmployeeRelationData> depts;

//Dept class 
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="DEPT_EMPLOYEE_MAPPING",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Dept_Id"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="Employee_Id")
    Map<Employee, DeptEmployeeRelationData> employees;

    @Embeddable
    class DeptemployeeRelationData {
      @Column(name="createdAt")
      DateTime createdAt;
    }
```

Your mapping is many to many.
Hope this will work!

Comment: what tables get created, if @ OneToMany is used? @ JoinColumn thing will it allow duplicates? The problem I have is - I randomly get a couple of dept ids and set to employee, if for another employee I get similar dept ids - constraint violation error

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
 @ManyToMany
 @OrderColumn
 private List<String> dept = new ArrayList<String>(4);
```

and working as per my requirement
DEPT, EMPLOYEE , EMPLOYEE_DEPT created